# Zoom switching controls in leaflet?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to add something (like a minimap control maybe) that would make the user aware that the deeper zoom levels have completely different set of markers.

I would like also to provide the user easy-access to these deep zoom levels, ie getting there without having to go through all levels in-between. Hence for example to click on that "minimap-like" control and jump directly to the target zoom level.

What I have done at the moment is a minimap control showing the high zoom level along with some markers (blue circleMarkers). This is fine but I what I would like now is to add "something" (on the same minimap?? another control with radio buttons, or thumbnails?? i dont really know...) that would be specific for the deeper zoom levels where the content (markers) is completely new. Note that the main map is populated with blue markers (across the whole world) when zoom level varies between 0 and 8 otherwise red markers are rendered (over most of Europe only).

Any ideas please?

I would like also to add that in practice the high-level markers (blue dots here) are about 60000 but the more granular info (red dots) are a couple of million! Thats the reason I cannot load all the red dots in one go but I load some slice of my data when zoom is deep enough and the browser can cope with the volume. In my actual code (not included in this example) I have also put in place an extra filter that slices the data (red markers here) based on the map's active viewing window.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!--jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <!-- leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <!-- minimap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-minimap/3.6.1/Control.MiniMap.min.css'/>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-minimap/3.6.1/Control.MiniMap.min.js'></script>

    <!-- clone layer -->
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-clonelayer@1.0.7/index.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function make_dots(color, N) {
        if (color === 'blue'){
            var a = -90,
                b = 180,
                c = -180,
                d = 360;
        }
        else {
            var a = -11,
                b = 38,
                c = 34,
                d = 24;
        }
        var dots = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            var g = {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [a + b * Math.random(), c + d * Math.random()]
            };

            var p = {
                color: color,
            };

            dots.features.push({
                "geometry": g,
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": p
            });
        }
        return dots;
    }


    function removeLayer(layer) {
        if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            console.log('Layer removed')
        }
    }

    function moveend(evt) {
            console.log('moveend event fired');

            var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
            if (zoomlevel <= 8) {
                removeLayer(red_layer);
                blue_layer.addTo(map);
            }

            if (zoomlevel > 8) {
                removeLayer(blue_layer);
                red_layer.addTo(map);
            }
    }

    blue_dots = make_dots('blue', 10000);
    red_dots = make_dots('red', 10000);
    var map = new L.Map('map');
    map.on('moveend', moveend);
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 18});

    var blue_renderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var blue_layer = L.geoJson(blue_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: blue_renderer,
            });
        }
    });

    var red_renderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var red_layer = L.geoJson(red_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: red_renderer,
            });
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(50, 1.0), 5);

    var osm2 = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 13});
    var blue_renderer_2 = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var blue_dots2 = L.geoJson(blue_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 2,
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: blue_renderer_2,
            });
        }
    });

    var layers = new L.LayerGroup([osm2, blue_dots2]);

    var miniMap = new L.Control.MiniMap(layers, {
        toggleDisplay: true,
        minimized: false,
        position: 'topright',
        zoomLevelFixed: 2,
    });
    miniMap.addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the mapbox tag, I assume you are also interested in hearing suggestions utuilizing mapbox technologies.

**OSM only approach:**

It appears that the problem is that the red dot layer with the minimap. I have changed your minimap to show the red dot layer instead of the blue dot layer and lowered the zoom level. You could add this as a second minimap to your map. Thereby you would have a minimap with red dots and one at high zoom level with blue dots.

Why would you want to make the minimap clickable? If you do that you cannot scroll around in it. You could add a different control. At its 'onClick' event you could set the map zoom to specific level using `map.setZoom(<ZoomLevel>);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!--jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <!-- leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

    <!-- minimap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-minimap/3.6.1/Control.MiniMap.min.css'/>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-minimap/3.6.1/Control.MiniMap.min.js'></script>

    <!-- clone layer -->
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-clonelayer@1.0.7/index.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<button id="button">Re-draw circle</button>
<script>
    function make_dots(color, N) {
        if (color === 'blue'){
            var a = -90,
                b = 180,
                c = -180,
                d = 360;
        }
        else {
            var a = -11,
                b = 38,
                c = 34,
                d = 24;
        }
        var dots = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            var g = {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [a + b * Math.random(), c + d * Math.random()]
            };

            var p = {
                color: color,
            };

            dots.features.push({
                "geometry": g,
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": p
            });
        }
        return dots;
    }


    function removeLayer(layer) {
        if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            console.log('Layer removed')
        }
    }

    function moveend(evt) {
            console.log('moveend event fired');

            var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
            if (zoomlevel <= 8) {
                removeLayer(red_layer);
                blue_layer.addTo(map);
            }

            if (zoomlevel > 8) {
                removeLayer(blue_layer);
                red_layer.addTo(map);
            }
    }

    blue_dots = make_dots('blue', 10000);
    red_dots = make_dots('red', 10000);
    var map = new L.Map('map');
    map.on('moveend', moveend);
    var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 18});

    var blue_renderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var blue_layer = L.geoJson(blue_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: blue_renderer,
            });
        }
    });

    var red_renderer = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var red_layer = L.geoJson(red_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: red_renderer,
            });
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(50, 1.0), 5);

    var osm2 = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 13});
    var blue_renderer_2 = L.canvas({
        padding: 0.5,
    });
    var blue_dots2 = L.geoJson(blue_dots, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 2,
                fillColor: feature.properties.color,
                color: feature.properties.color,
                renderer: blue_renderer_2,
            });
        }
    });

    var layers = new L.LayerGroup([osm2, red_layer]);

    var miniMap = new L.Control.MiniMap(layers, {
        toggleDisplay: true,
        minimized: false,
        position: 'topright',
        zoomLevelFixed: 9,
    });
 
    miniMap.addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Mapbox approach:**

Another approach could be to use Mapbox technologies and add the red and blue dots to your map style. In that approach you have the option (with Mapbox) to make certain layers only visible in specific zoom ranges. You would not have to care about that in your JS code. By changing the zoom in your minimap, you can see the red dots at low zoom. (zoomed-in)

Comment: Thanks Moritz, I might not have understood your solution completely and I might as welll havent explained my problem very clearly. I would like to give users the ability to switch from zoom level, lets say 3 to 8. When a user views the map at zoom=3 he doesnt know that there is a different kind of info at the deeper zoom levels, unless he manually goes through all levels from 3 to 8. If that for some reason doesnt happen users wont be aware of the extra, more granular, info at levels>8. This is what I want to do, it doesnt have to be a clickable minimap, i just dont know how to do it.

Comment: Ok I get it. The code I have shared will change your minimap to display the world at zoom level 9 and show the red_dot layer. At the same time the big map will be at a zoom level that shows the blue_dot layer. I have suggested to create a separate control that if clicked will set your big map to a different zoom level. Let me know if something is unclear! I will gladly explain :)